# Upgrading Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, nodetool

my Cassandra version is `1.2.4` and i'm trying to upgrade it to `2.0.5` and i know that in the first part i have to upgrade it to `1.0.14` and after that try to upgrade it to the `2.0.5` ,

when I try to run `nodetool -h localhost removenode Host ID` it gives me :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot remove self
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.removeNode(StorageService.java:3199)
>   .....

before running that command i tried `nodetool upgradesstables`

what is the problem ? and how can i resolve it ?

---

OS:Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

1. Download the versions 1.2.13 and 2.0.5 of Cassandra from the official site . Unpack . Configure cassandra.yaml in both versions downloaded Cassandra. Take as a basis the existing (old) version cassandra.yaml.
2. Make snapshot for old Cassandra: nodetool snapshot.
3. Stop recording unit (reading will continue to work): nodetool drain.
4. Stop old Cassandra.
5. Copy the data from the current (old) Cassandra in a new version 1.2.13. Run it (1.2.13).
6. Perform for Cassandra 1.2.13 update command table format: nodetool upgradesstables-a.
7. Copy data from Cassandra 1.2.13 to Cassandra 2.0.5.

**FINE POINTS**

1. In 2.0.5 are included by default virtual hosts - vnodes (record "num_tokens: 256" in cassandra.yaml).
2. In 2.0.5 record "index_interval: 128" factored out of the file cassandra.yaml to the level properties of the table.
3. In 2.0.5 some settings from previous versions of cassandra.yaml are absent.

Comment: tank you Dmitry, but the problem is not upgrading , i have done it successfully , the problem is `removenode` command

Comment: Ok. Ensure in right format of Host ID (UUID format) and try removenode command from another machine. Seems it isn't possible run this command on the node must be removed. See more here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRemoveNode.html